# exit tail when other process is done

Tags: tail

I have

```
parallel --j 2 -- "sh script1" "sh script2"
```

where `script1` and `script2` log in files `log1` and `log2`

I would like to change this to:

```
parallel --j 3 -- "sh script1" "sh script2" "tail -f log1 log2"
```

The reason to use tail is when I allow the two scripts to output on the screen at the same time - the output becomes a mess and I lose the cursor etc issues - I need to restart the terminal almost after every execution.

The problem though is that now this will go forever and I would like tail to exit when script1 and script2 are done. How I can do that?

Comment: Could you edit the Q to include the OS we're running under? (as a tag or as text, or both)

Comment: If any of the existing answers solves your problem, please consider accepting it via the checkmark. Thank you!

Comment: To tail log until process ends, but watch process output at the same time, try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60134868/658497

Answer (score 2, accepted):

actually, I found what I need to do:

```
parallel --j 2 -- "sh script1" "sh script2" &
PID=$!
tail --pid=$PID -f log1 log2
```

Comment: Be careful of tail's `--pid=$PID`, it's painfully slow in my experience (adds a second or so on exit). An exit trap is faster, but not as robust imo.

Answer (score 2):

This may *also* not be what you want, but how about:

```
parallel --j 2 -- "sh script1" "sh script2"; tail log1 log2
```

Once both jobs are done, you get the non-waiting `tail` of both log files.

Comment: scripts are really long term and I would like to be able to look at from time to time and see how it is going

Comment: tail the log files when you get curious?

Comment: that exactly to point of the question - how to make it part of the script, because I am sure that I will get curious at several points, so I would like the script to do it for me

Answer (score 0):

Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> once the scripts are done to kill the tail manually.

Comment: I can, but this will stop the execution of the rest of the script

Comment: actually if I am careful to do it once it won't,  but it still going to wait for me before proceed further, which is not what I want

Comment: This is a question, not an answer.

Comment: This is incredibly not a question; you guys have to stop flagging everything that ends in a question mark

Comment: It might not be a question, but it is not answer of the question as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Multitail](https://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/index.php) or [tmux](https://tmux.github.io/).

Comment: How, and why would you?

Answer (score 0):

`parallel --j 2 -- "sh script1" "sh script2" & tail -f log1 log2`

This runs `parallel ...` in the background and then runs `tail ...`.

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> on the tail won't effect the `parallel` jobs.

If you need to bring the `parallel` to the foreground, kill the `tail` and type `fg`.  To send it to the background again (e.g. so you can run `tail` once more), press <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd> and type `bg`.  Or you can kill it with `kill %%`

See your shell documentation for more details.  e.g. if you are using bash, run `man bash` and search for (all-caps) `JOB CONTROL`.